# Perform action when access token is generated

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

**Context**

Current [AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/oauth2/config/annotation/web/configuration/AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.html) configured with the following:

- OAuth2 grant type of "implicit"
- Authentication process made with a custom Filter
- Authorize endpoint generating JWT access token.

While testing it manually (or by integration test), we got a confirmation prompt based on provided scope and a redirection made with our generated access_token, so it works pretty good.

**Question**

I try to figure out how to attach a listener or whatever for this new token's generation phase.

Would need to do some stuff with this access token like storing it, bind it with some [authentication](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html) details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at then I found a way to attach in TokenStore (JwtTokenStore implementation).

```
@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    JwtTokenStore store = new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter()) {
        @Override
        public void storeAccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken token, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
            // HERE
        }
    };

    return store;
}
```